# variable scope inside the try block when accessing from the finally block?

Tags: java, try-catch, block, scope, finally

I noticed that when the following variables when in try { }, I couldn't use methods on them from finally for example:

```
import java.io.*;
public class Main 
{
    public static void main() throws FileNotFoundException
    {

    try {
           File src = new File("src.txt");
           File des = new File("des.txt");
           /*code*/
     }
     finally {
              try { 
                   /*closing code*/
                  System.out.print("After closing files:Size of src.txt:"+src.length()+" Bytes\t");
                  System.out.println("Size of des.txt:"+des.length()+" Bytes");
                  } catch (IOException io){
                       System.out.println("Error while closing Files:"+io.toString());
                  }
            }
     }
}
```

But when the declarations where placed in `main()` before the `try{}` the program compiled with no errors,
Could someone point me the solution/answer/workaround?

Comment: `when the declarations where placed in main() before Try{ }` That is the solution. Declare the variable in a greater scope.

Comment: There is no work around.  This is expected behavior in java.  Variable scope is strict.

Comment: If you declared any variable inside block like `{` or `}`, so it can't accessible outside scope.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to declare your variables before you enter your `try` block, so that they remain in scope for the rest of your method:

```
public static void main() throws FileNotFoundException {
    File src = null;
    File des = null;
    try {
        src = new File("src.txt");
        des = new File("des.txt");
        /*code*/
    } finally {
        /*closing code*/
        if (src != null) {
            System.out.print("After closing files:Size of src.txt:" + src.length() + " Bytes\t");
        }
        if (des != null) {
            System.out.println("Size of des.txt:" + des.length() + " Bytes");
        }
    }
}
```